# How can I add modules to React Quill v1.3.3

Tags: reactjs, react-quill

```
const App = ({ }) => {
    const [message, setMessage] = React.useState('')
    ReactQuill.Quill.import('modules/matchers')
    ReactQuill.Quill.register("imageResize", ImageResize)
    const modules = {
        toolbar: [
            [{ header: '1' }, { header: '2' }, { font: [] }],
            //[{ size: [] }],
            ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike', 'link'],
            [{ 'color': [] }, { 'background': [] }], 
            //[{ 'font': [] }],
            [{ 'align': [] }],
            ['blockquote', 'code-block'],
            ['image'],
            [
                { list: 'ordered' },
                { list: 'bullet' },
                { indent: '-1' },
                { indent: '+1' }
            ],
            ['clean']
        ],
        clipboard: {
            matchVisual: false,
            matchers: [
                ['span', preserveSizeFormat]
            ]
        },
        imageResize: {
            parchment: ReactQuill.Quill.import('parchment'),
            modules : ['Resize', 'DisplaySize']
        },
        mention: {
            allowedChars: /^[A-Za-z\sÅÄÖåäö]*$/,
            mentionDenotationChars: ["@", "#"],
            source: function (searchTerm, renderList, mentionChar) {
                console.log('mention',searchTerm, renderList, mentionChar)
            }
        }
    }

    const preserveSizeFormat = (node, delta) => {
        console.log('node',node,'delta',delta)
    }
    return <ReactQuill value={message} onChange={(html) => { console.log('html',html); setMessage(html) }} placeholder={''} modules={modules}  />
}
```

I'm  trying to add mention, image resize and clipboard matcher but it doesn't work when I try to import or register.

I have this errors :

[image: errors]

Someone have any idea to make it works ?

I have the version 1.3.3 of react-quill